# Symfony2 form collection with custom labels

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have an object - Book with Persons collection inside (each person has **name property**) and I need to create a form type persons it is a collection simply checkbox but I would like to have as a label on each checkbox persons name how to do it ?

I have BookType:

```
$builder->add('persons', 'collection', array(
    'type'   => 'checkbox',
    'options'  => array(
        'required'  => false,
    ),
));
```

**How to add label with persons name** ??

Comment: You should customize the `prototype` of the collection widget. [This solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555702/how-to-customize-the-data-prototype-attribute-in-symfony-2-forms#answer-9545936) should work.

Comment: Why don't you use `Entity` as form type ? You can set `expanded` and `multiple` to `true` to have it rendered as checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question, but I'll try to help you anyway.

Did you already tried this?

```
$builder->add('persons','entity', array(
                'class'     => 'VendorBundle:Entity',
                'property'  => 'name',
                'label'     => 'YourLabel'
            ))
```

(Adapt the code for your configurations by changing 'VendorBundle:Entity' and 'YourLabel' )

This adds a field in your form which has the 'property name' of each 'VendorBundle:Person' and has a label 'YourLabel' right before the dropdown field.