# Form collection and form_widgets in symfony

Tags: forms, symfony, collections, twig

I have this photo form:

**PhotoType.php**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('title');
```

And I embed this form in a form collection:

**PhotoCollectionType.php**

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
      $builder->add('photos', 'collection', array(
        'type'         => new PhotoType($this->securityContext,  $this->id),
        'allow_add'    => true,
        'allow_delete' => true
      ))
      ->add('save',      'submit');
```

How can I get the `form_widget` title alone?

I tried these:

```
{{ form(formCollection) }} -> works but not what i want
{{ form_widget(formCollection.title) }} -> no work
{{ form_widget(formCollection.photo.title) }} -> nop
{{ form_widget(formCollection.photos.title) }} -> oh wait !! .. no.
{{ form_widget(title) }} -> lol no.
```

Error being

```
Method "title" for object "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" does not exist
```

edit : Oh and i should say the form is generated with js , for the allow_add allow_delete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{% for photo in form.photos %}
    {{ form_widget(photo.title) }}
{% endfor %}
```

is this are you looking for?

Comment: With javascript generation you have to deal with the data-prototype attribute so its a bit more complicated, i followed this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/17875399/3876501 , with a twig macro. 
but your answer guided me so i give you my blessing