# How can I customize prototype widget templates for a single property?

Tags: php, symfony, templates, symfony-forms

In my application, I have classes A and B. Objects of class A own many objects of class B.

To edit these objects, I have a compound form. The outer form edits the properties of object A and the inner form edits all the owned instances of B. This subform is supposed to display its entries as table rows. The table itself is defined by the outer form.

My project is using the PHP templating engine. So far, I have managed to overwrite the template widget to edit an object of type B. The property of A holding all instances of B is rendered as `collection` into the form. This means the following templates are rendered: collection_widget.html.php -> form_widget_compound.html.php -> form_rows.html.php -> form_row.html.php -> 
my_custom_template_widget.html.php

However, some of these templates add  tags to surround the templates they are rendering which destroys my table layout. I have managed to fix this by overwriting the template for this property by creating _formForA_propertyB_widget.html.php and rendering everything manually in there.

The problem I have now is that it should be possible to add objects to this collection. I want to do this using the prototype functionality provided by Symfony. However, it seems the prototype is not created using my overwritten template (of course not, as this is for a collection and not for a single row) but instead is created using form_row.html.php. I have tried overwriting this by creating _formForA_propertyB_form.html.php but this did not make any difference.

How can I overwrite the prototype template for this specific property?

Essentially this question is very similar to [How to customize the data-prototype attribute in Symfony 2 forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555702/how-to-customize-the-data-prototype-attribute-in-symfony-2-forms) but this one is about using PHP as a templating engine. Answers on the other question use features of the TWIG templating engine which are not available with the PHP engine.

---

Sample code to illustrate the problem:

Views/EditA.html.php:

```
<table data-prototype="<?php echo $view->escape($view['form']->row($form['collectionOfB']->vars['prototype'])) ?>">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Prop1</th>
        <th>Prop2</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <?php echo $view['form']->widget($form['collectionOfB']) ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Views/Form/_objectA_collectionOfB_widget.html.php:

```
<?php foreach ($form as $child) : ?>
    <?php echo $view['form']->widget($child) ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Views/Form/objectB_widget.html.php:

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $view['form']->widget($form['description']) ?>
        <?php echo $view['form']->errors($form['description']) ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $view['form']->widget($form['prop1']) ?>
        <?php echo $view['form']->errors($form['prop1']) ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $view['form']->widget($form['prop2']) ?>
        <?php echo $view['form']->errors($form['prop2']) ?></td>
</tr>
```

As I said, the form is rendered correctly, but this is the prototype:

```
<div>
    <label class="required" >__name__label__</label>
    <tr>
    <!-- snip more code here -->
    </tr>
</div>
```

You can see that this contains the `label` and a `div`, both of which I do not want as it will destroy the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the answer is way simpler than I thought. Instead of rendering the entire row (and thereby rendering the form_row.html.php template containing a `div`) I need to render the widget only.

Basically all you need to do is replace

```
$view->escape($view['form']->row($form['collectionOfB']->vars['prototype']))
```

with

```
$view->escape($view['form']->widget($form['collectionOfB']->vars['prototype']))
```