# Symfony3 Variable does not exist in including template

Tags: php, twig, symfony

I get the following error: Variable "file" does not exist.

The included template **Contractor:file.html.twig** looks like this:

```
{{ dump(file) }}
```

The main template **form.html.twig** looks like this:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
{% form_theme form 'NaSoftEdmBundle:Form:fields.html.twig' %}

...

{% block files %}
  {% for file in form.files %}
     {{ include('NaSoftEdmBundle:Contractor:file.html.twig', {'file': file}) }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Controller:

```
public function editAction(Request $request, Contractor $contractor)
{
    ...
    return $this->render('NaSoftEdmBundle:Contractor:form.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

---

But when I try to display a variable inside the main template file (form.html.twig), the variable becomes available:

```
{% for file in form.files %}
   {{ dump(file) }} {# it work! #}
{% endfor %}


ContractorFile {#499 ▼
 -id: 154
 -uploadedFile: null
 -name: "57c6d217d9a92.jpg"
 -origName: "1471590585502.jpg"
 -path: "/contractor/docs/files/2/335"
 -size: 153536
 -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
 -updateDate: DateTime {#496 ▶}
 -contractor: Contractor {#370 ▶}
}
```

command `php app/console cache:clear` did not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was before starting the cycle "for" included the same template for attribute **data-prototype**:

```
data-prototype="{% filter escape %} 
     {% include 'NaSoftEdmBundle: Contractor: file.html.twig' with { '_form':form.files.vars.prototype} %}
{% endfilter %}"
```

I've created for the attribute "data-prototype" new template and it worked.

```
data-prototype="{% filter escape %} 
     {% include 'NaSoftEdmBundle: Contractor: filePrototype.html.twig' with { 'file':_form.files.vars.prototype} %}
{% endfilter %}"
```

This has been implemented to customize the template collection

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to pass variables to a Twig `include` command is this:

```
{% include 'NaSoftEdmBundle:Contractor:file.html.twig' with {'file': file} %}
```

As @walther pointed out in comments, it is not actually required to pass variables since an included template get access to variables of the active context, i.e. you can simply write:

```
{% include 'NaSoftEdmBundle:Contractor:file.html.twig' %}
```

and the `file` variable will be used.

You still have to use the `with` syntax if you want to assign a new variable, e.g.

```
{% include 'NaSoftEdmBundle:Contractor:files.html.twig' with {'files': form.files} %}
```

See http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html

Comment: Whoops! Thanks for pointing out my mistake. Fixed the answer.

Comment: No problem. By the way, wouldn't simply including the file suffice in this case? According to docs the included file should have access to the variables of the current context. Can't test it right now, so not sure though.

Comment: You are once again correct :-) I tested it right now. I extended my answer to give all available options.

Comment: I was guided by this documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html#including-other-templates still not work( I can not send in any variable to file.html.twig

Comment: for some reason it does not work inheritance variables in Twig

Comment: @acanthis in fact there is an `include` **tag** (http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html) and an `include` **function** (http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/include.html) that work in the same way. 
My answer explains how the tag version works, but yours should work as well (just tested both).

Comment: @Francesco Abeni I'm confused. For here it is: {% include 'NaSoftEdmBundle: Contractor: file.html.twig' with { 'test': 123} %} I get this: Variable "test" does not exist in NaSoftEdmBundle: Contractor: file.html.twig at line 1. Maybe inheritance variables in Twig  configured in configs?

Comment: variable "form" and "form.files" are available in the template file.html.twig

Comment: I am unable to reproduce. Everything works as expected on a brand new Symfony 3.1. project. I am not aware of any configuration to disable this specific Twig behaviour, so I'm out of suggestions, sorry.

Comment: @francesco-abeni I think I found the reason for this behavior twig. The fact is that before the cycle I have deduced custiom data-prototype: `data-prototype="{% filter escape%} {% include 'NaSoftEdmBundle: Contractor: file.html.twig' with { 'file': form.files. vars.prototype}%} {% endfilter%}"`( See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555702/how-to-customize-the-data-prototype-attribute-in-symfony-2-forms)) If you remove it, everything works. How do I then print the data-prototype with its pattern?

Comment: "As of Twig 1.12, it is recommended to use the include function instead as it provides the same features with a bit more flexibility"
https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/include.html